# How could I write the right entry point in Spark 2.0 program (Actually pyspark 2.0)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Today, I wanna try some new features with Spark2.0, here is my program:

```
#coding:utf-8
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('test 2.0').config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/Spark2/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
df.show()
```

but it errors as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/kiseliugit/MyPysparkCodes/test/spark2.0.py", line 5, in <module>
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('test 2.0').config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/Spark2/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/Spark2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 243, in _ensure_initialized
SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/Spark2/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 116, in launch_gateway
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.SparkConf")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 90, in java_import
return_value = get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, None, None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 306, in get_return_value
value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
KeyError: u'y'
```

What's wrong with these few lines of codes? Does it have the problem with java environment? Plus, I use IDE PyCharm for developing.

Answer (score 14):

Try to upgrade py4j, pip install py4j --upgrade

It's worked for me.